# is the SambaStream Recurly library abandoned?

Tags: java, grails, recurly

#### Background

I have a third party library in an application I've taken over called `SambaJam-RecurlyLibrary-patched.jar`.  The namespace for the library is `com.sambastream.recurly`.

The only evidence I've found of this product is a startup called SambaStream, but [they were acquired](http://www.crunchbase.com/company/sambastream) over a year ago. The acquiring company (Alfresco) doesn't appear to have any `recurly`-oriented products.

I also looked at the [only other grails/recurly library I found](http://grails.org/plugin/recurly), thinking that it was renamed; but after looking at the namespace and file names, that seems *unlikely*.

#### Question

Does anyone know what happened to the `com.sambastream.recurly` library?

Comment: Off topic?  Does someone mind explaining why?

Comment: Edited the question and re-opened.  If it gets closed again, that would be a *strong signal* that it's considered `off topic`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had edited a bit myself, but the question clearly benefits from your changes.  I need to practice using fewer words.